# Variable use during recursion?

Tags: python, variables, recursion, scope

So, I am trying to solve a problem which involves finding the maximum depth of a tuple (for example, depth(('a',('b','c','d'),('e','f','g'))) should return 2 and depth(('a', ('b',), ('c', ('d', ('e',), f), ('g', 'h', 'i')))) should return 4.
I am trying to use recursion to solve the problem where I use a counter 'c' to keep track of depth of each tuple (within the main tuple). The problem is,I get the following error, **local variable 's' referenced before assignment**.

My code is something like:

```
s=0
def depth(tuple):
     do something
     s=s+1
     depth(some_nested_tuple)
     return
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with your `global` variable inside a function you have to do it like this:

```
s=0
def depth(tuple):
     # do something
     global s
     s=s+1
     return depth(some_nested_tuple)
```